# How do I get bearer token from DRF using React?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios, bearer-token

I have a backend built using DRF, and frontend using React and axios. Once someone logs in, the server issues a csrf token and session id. Is there anyway I can extract the server-generated Bearer token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first install the rest framework authtoken,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
]
```

then include this in settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        )
    }
```

and then login and get the key as -

```
axios
  .post("https://www.example.com/rest-auth/login/", {
    username: username,
    password: password,
  }).then((res) => {
      const token = res.data.key;
    })
```